# Cannot Drag UIImageView upto the end of the UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have an UIScrollview with large content in horizontal. Now I want to drag a UIImageView upto the end of the UIScrollView. For that i'm using the following code.

```
- (void) setUpLeftGesture{

    _leftControlImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 80, 25)];
    [_leftControlImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [_leftControlImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_left_normal"]];
    //add gesture events
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSelector:)];
    [_leftControlImageView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
    [_leftControlImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView addSubview:_leftControlImageView];

}

-(void)handleLeftSelector:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer{

    CGPoint point = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
    _leftControlImageView.center = point;
}
```

When i execute the above code I can drag the _leftControlImageView (my UIImageView) is moving fine within the screensize.

If i try to drag to the end of the UIScrollView, the UIImageView not dragging. I again gets back to the previous position. I don't have idea why it's happened.

Thanks in advance. Can anyone please provide any suggestions to drag a view upto the end of the UIScrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to drag a view upto the end of the UIScrollView. Please make sure your view (CustomView) is extended to the UIScrollView or not. I think UIPanGestureRecognizer will allow us to perform Drag and Drop within it's super class.

So Change your super class from UIView to UIScrollView, As like this.

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
```

to

```
@interface CustomView : UIScrollView
```

By doing so you can drag a UIView upto the end of the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Add imageview in your content view not in scrollview.